# Magento 2 OnePage checkout new step

Tags: magento, magento2

I have added one new step by following this article

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

But in my case both steps are enabled togather

[image]

Can you please let me know why it is happening? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Actually, it is a programming related question. But more specifically related to the Magento 2 programming or module development. And Magento 2 modules are also developed in PHP programming. And yes magento.stackexchange.com is more related to it but we can not post a specific framework related question on stackover flow with the tags of that specific framework?

Comment: Then please show your code and explain what's not working and what you need help with. That's what we're here for.

Comment: I have added the article which I follow to add the new step. And that code is long that's why I just add the link not the code here in Stackoverflow for precise question. I have found the answer. Soon I will answer this question.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless it is to support content you have already put in the question. You should post a [mcve] so that we can help you.